# JSF <h:selectOneMenu> valueChangeListener does not work

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, valuechangelistener

Hi I have a jsp page like this

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
    <f:loadBundle basename="amdocs.gcreport.messages" var="msg" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.environmens}"></h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectEnv" value="#{gCAnalyzerController.envName}" onchange="submit();" valueChangeListener="#{gCAnalyzerController.envValueChange}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{gCAnalyzerController.envs}" var="env" itemValue="#{env.name}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>  
    </h:panelGrid>
.
.
.
```

whenever I change value in this dropdown listbox, the function envValueChange should be called in the bean class. However when run this piece of code in IE I got exception "Error: Object expected", when trying to debug in google chrome, I got the below exception.

Uncaught ReferenceError: submit is not defined GCAnalyzerView.jsp:15
onchange

It looks like the javascript submit() is not defined anywhere so the page can not load it, can anyone tell me where and how should I implement this javascript method?

Comment: Please don't post the answer inside the question. Just post it as an answer when the time allows it (and for sure don't put "Resolved" or something in the title, just mark the answer accepted)

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

The code should be included in a form tag for submit.

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.environmens}"></h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:selectOneMenu id="selectEnv" value="#{gCAnalyzerController.envName}" onchange="submit();" valueChangeListener="#{gCAnalyzerController.envValueChange}" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{gCAnalyzerController.envs}" var="env" itemValue="#{env.name}"/>
        </h:selectOneMenu>  
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```